# administrate gem customizing labels used for resources in dashboard collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administrate

The administrate gem [guide](https://administrate-demo.herokuapp.com/customizing_dashboards)  indicates the labels for ressources can be adapted to attributes of that model

```
def display_resource(user)
  user.name
end
```

However this does not appear to function on relations

`Card` belongs_to `User`  and the goal is to represent the ressource user in the CardDashboard with

```
card.user.last_name + ', ' + card.user.first_name
```

However, even a succinct definition

```
def display_resource(user)
  card.user.last_name
end
```

leads to `undefined local variable or method 'card' for #<CardDashboard`

It appears the display_resource definition is only applicable to its own class as

```
def display_resource(user)
  user.last_name + ', ' + user.first_name
end
```

will work.

Is there a mechanism by which the resource label can be defined on a per-class basis using nested attributes ?

**update**  error stack

```
app/dashboards/user_dashboard.rb:212:in `display_resource'
app/views/admin/cards/_form.html.erb:38
app/views/admin/cards/_form.html.erb:36:in `each'
app/views/admin/cards/_form.html.erb:36
app/views/admin/cards/_form.html.erb:17
app/views/admin/cards/edit.html.erb:35
```

**update**

Full stack trace

```
administrate (0.14.0) lib/administrate/base_dashboard.rb:39:in `block in attribute_type_for'
administrate (0.14.0) lib/administrate/base_dashboard.rb:38:in `fetch'
administrate (0.14.0) lib/administrate/base_dashboard.rb:38:in `attribute_type_for'
administrate (0.14.0) lib/administrate/page/base.rb:30:in `attribute_field'
administrate (0.14.0) lib/administrate/page/form.rb:15:in `block in attributes'
administrate (0.14.0) lib/administrate/page/form.rb:14:in `map'
administrate (0.14.0) lib/administrate/page/form.rb:14:in `attributes'
app/views/admin/cards/_form.html.erb:36
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:45:in `block in capture'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:209:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:45:in `capture'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:452:in `form_for'
client_side_validations (17.2.0) lib/client_side_validations/action_view/form_helper.rb:11:in `form_for'
app/views/admin/cards/_form.html.erb:17
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/base.rb:274:in `_run'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:185:in `block in render'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:385:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:183:in `render'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:357:in `block in render_partial'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:88:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:87:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:346:in `render_partial'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:317:in `render'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:65:in `render_partial_to_object'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:53:in `render_partial'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:38:in `render'
app/views/admin/cards/edit.html.erb:35
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/base.rb:274:in `_run'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:185:in `block in render'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:385:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:183:in `render'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:88:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:87:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:57:in `block in render_template'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:65:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_template'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:13:in `render'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:61:in `render_template_to_object'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:29:in `render_to_object'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:117:in `block in _render_template'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/base.rb:304:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:116:in `_render_template'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:218:in `_render_template'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `block in ms'
/home/uelcom/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (6.0.3.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
administrate (0.14.0) app/controllers/administrate/application_controller.rb:38:in `edit'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:195:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.3.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.3.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.3.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:19:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.3.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.3.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rails_same_site_cookie (0.1.8) lib/rails_same_site_cookie/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
webpacker (4.3.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:107:in `process_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

**Update_Dashboards**

```
require "administrate/base_dashboard"

class CardDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    user: Field::BelongsTo.with_options(
      searchable: true,
      searchable_fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile']
    ),
    id: Field::Number,
    virtual: Field::Boolean,
    blocked: Field::Boolean,
    code: Field::String,
    created_at: Field::DateTime,
    updated_at: Field::DateTime,
  }.freeze

  COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
  user
  id
  virtual
  blocked
  ].freeze

  SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
  user
  id
  virtual
  blocked
  code
  created_at
  updated_at
  ].freeze

  FORM_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
  user
  virtual
  blocked
  code
  ].freeze

  COLLECTION_FILTERS = {}.freeze


  def display_resource(card)
    card.user.last_name + ', ' + card.user.first_name
  end


end

require "administrate/base_dashboard"

class UserDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    nation: Field::BelongsTo,
    card: Field::HasOne,
    notifications: Field::HasMany,
    attachments: Field::HasMany,
    id: Field::Number,
    last_user_update: Field::Number,
    last_user_update_at: Field::DateTime,
    created_at: Field::DateTime,
    updated_at: Field::DateTime,
  }.freeze

  COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
  id
  email
  mobile
  login_name
  municipal
  newsletter
  ].freeze

  SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
  nation
  card
  notifications
  attachments
  id
  email
  first_name
  last_name
  date_of_birth
  address
  storage_bin
  created_at
  updated_at
  ].freeze

  FORM_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
  nation
  card
  notifications
  attachments
  email
  mobile
  ].freeze

  COLLECTION_FILTERS = {}.freeze
    
  def display_resource(user)
      user ? user.last_name + ', ' + user.first_name : "No user selected"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to represent cards in the `CardDashboard` as follows:

```rb
card.user.last_name + ', ' + card.user.first_name
```

Then you use this code example, which is not working:

```
def display_resource(user)
  card.user.last_name
end
```

I'm probably missing some info, and your example might have a typo, but what I would expect you to have is the following instead:

```rb
def display_resource(card)
  card.user.last_name
end
```

The method `CardDashboard#display_resource` will receive **cards** as arguments, not **users**. You can't refer to `card` in your example because it's not defined (your argument is `user` instead). My example however should work, although it will represent the card as first_name+last_name everywhere, not just when represented as associations in other dashboards.

Comment: Sorry, I may have gotten wires crossed in the past 3 weeks.  Defining `display resource(card)`in CardDashboard does not kick in as the error's stack is pointing to the UserDashboard which defines `display_resource(user)` even though the URL invoked is `/admin/cards/178/edit` Question updated. Maybe there is misdirection occurring?

Comment: To display a record, Administrate calls `display_resource` on the dashboard of the record's class. To represent a user, it calls `UserDashboard#display_resource`, regardless of which dashboard the user appears in. So if "card belongs_to user", and you show the user in the cards dashboard, it will still try `UserDashboard#display_resource`.

Comment: Very helpful; the problem has been narrowed down significantly. `ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {    user: Field::BelongsTo.with_options([...]`  SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES provide the user display ressource, but for edit  FORM_ATTRIBUTES `user` returns undefined method  '+'  trying to render `user.last_name + ', ' + user.first_name`; thus it has no apparent user.  Providing `user_id` as a form attribute returns `Attribute user_id could not be found in CardDashboard::ATTRIBUTE_TYPES` when it appears it is.  I am still missing something...

Comment: Can you update the question with the new stack trace please? Which options are you using with `BelongsTo`? I wonder if the problem is that you are getting a `nil` in `display_resource` and you should be guarding against it: `user ? user.last_name + ', ' + user.first_name : "No user selected"`.

Comment: question updated.  `with_options( searchable: true, searchable_fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile']    )`   I am not getting nil, as the show action for the same object renders.  However implementing your 'guard'  the error returns something more pertinent:  ` Attribute user_id could not be found in CardDashboard::ATTRIBUTE_TYPES` .  Still it is odd given the dashboard's definition of `user: Field::BelongsTo.with_options`

Comment: Can you update the question with the two dashboards, please? (`CardDashboard` and `UserDashboard`). It looks like you have `user_id` listed as attribute in `CardDashboard`, when it should be `user`, but it's not clear. Also please share the models, not completely, just the relevant pieces: initial declaration, associations, anything else that may be relevant.

Comment: updated, while removing cruft of unrelevant variables to assist legibility. Note: base dashboard is not existent in my app `/dashboards`  directory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help. I don't see anything wrong, and in any case the question has evolved out of the original formulation and it's difficult to follow. I do see that you have custom templates for `edit` and `_form`, so perhaps those are introducing a problem, but I can't tell. I recommend that you clone the gem, bundle it locally with your project, and try debug the issue yourself. It may feel daunting, but it'll help you understand what's going on and may be the only way to solve your issue.